# SQL join per unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

[image]

I am trying to join both tables on product ID, but I am not able to produce the expected outcome. I tried left join on product ID, but it didn't produce the null value or fill in the missing product ID per country.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are using.  SQL Server or Postgres?

Comment: Can you put the SQL you tried? Seems like a simple inner join should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows, then a `left join`:

```
select c.country, t2.product_id, t1.cost
from (select distinct country from table1) c cross join
     table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.country = c.country and t1.product_id = t2.product_id
order by c.country, t2.product_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the required output:

```
Select t1.counry, t1.productId, t2.cost
From table_1 t1
cross join table_2 t2
```